# Remove a folder if registry entry is not present

Tags: wix, windows-installer, conditional-statements, bootstrapper, burn

I need to remove a folder if a certain folder path in registry doesn't exist. I wrote the below code but it doesn't work. The folder is not deleted and nothing about a condition check in the logs as well.

```
 <Property Id="UPDATERSERVICEFOLDER">
  <RegistrySearch Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UpdaterService\Parameters" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Id="UpdateDirectoryRegistrySearch" Name="UpdaterServicePath" />
</Property>

  <Component Id="RemoveFolder" Directory="MyProgramDir" Guid="*" >
    <RemoveFolder Id="MosquittoInstallDir" On="uninstall"/>
    <Condition><![CDATA[UPDATERSERVICEFOLDER]]></Condition>
  </Component>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

RemoveFolder won't remove the folder if there is **anything** in the folder when the component is processed. The issue you probably have is that this component gets processed before all the other components that represent something in that folder are processed or there are files that are not part of your install in this folder.

I don't know if there is a way to force a component to be processed last. An alternative you can try is [Util:RemoveFolderEx](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html). It is very important to note the remark at the bottom of this page. What this is basically saying is that you can't use a directory property to define the path to remove; you can't use [MyProgramDir] as the Property. The suggested way to implement the Property for this Util:RemoveFolderEx is to use a registry search to get the correct path then use that property set by the registry search.

Comment: The issue with using RemoveFolderEx is that it doesn't support conditions right? Is it possible using RemoveFolderEx to check if a registry value exists and then remove the folder? If so can you help me with an example :(

Comment: If you want to conditionally remove a folder on the uninstall I think you would be best off writing a custom action to delete the folder when uninstalling if your condition is met.